# Function not found although it is in the bundle.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

index.html:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        ...
        getXYCookieValue()
        ...
    }
</script>

<body>
...
<script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

webpack-config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        entry: __dirname + '/src/cookieHandler.js'
    },
    output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
},
```

}

cookieHandler.js

```
function getXYCookieValue() {
    // returns xy cookie value
}
```

server.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
```

If I GET localhost:3000/bundle.js the file gets returned and i see the getXYCookieValue() function in it. However, when i try to use it in the index.html, i get the

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getXYCookieValue is not defined
```

error.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Does the bundle.js load first before the function declaration?

Comment: How can i confirm that?

Comment: You can try viewing the source code on the browser. :)

Comment: If you mean, whether the  `<script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` resides above the usage of the function, then yes, it doesnt make any difference.

Comment: As I see on your index.html code, your script bundle.js is being loaded after you call getXYCookieValue function. Since this function is declared under bundle.js, the browser will not find it since it is not yet loaded.

Comment: Read my answer above, it doesn't make any difference if i put the bunlde.js first.

Comment: The "DOMContentLoaded" event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading. Please try changing it to "load".

Comment: @lebigmac did you figure this out?

Comment: @james I did but it was over 2 years ago, I don't remember anymore what the problem was, but it was something trivial, thats all I can remember